# Android : How to display a string data in EditView and in TextView also

Tags: android, view, ip

Ok, I've an activity in which user gets to know his/her IP Address, the IP is displayed in a `TextView` but I want it to display in an `EditView` for easy copy pasting. Here's my code...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ip);

    getWindow
    ().setSoftInputMode(
        WindowManager.
        LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    try {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
             NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
             for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                 InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                 if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                    TextView ipView= (TextView) findViewById(R.string.ip);
                    ipView.setText(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                 }
             }
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("------------", e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement inside the for loop; you can just use edit text normally like :

```
EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et1.setText(your ip address string );
```

To be more specific;

Here's your code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            try {
                for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> en = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); en.hasMoreElements();) {
                     NetworkInterface intf = en.nextElement();
                     for (Enumeration<InetAddress> enumIpAddr = intf.getInetAddresses(); enumIpAddr.hasMoreElements();) {
                         InetAddress inetAddress = enumIpAddr.nextElement();
                         if (!inetAddress.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                            /*TextView ipView= (TextView) findViewById(R.string.ip);
                            ipView.setText(inetAddress.getHostAddress());*/
                             Log.e("IP------------", inetAddress.getHostAddress());

                        //Here you can set the EditText and the TextView value.
                TextView ipView= (TextView) findViewById(R.string.ip);
                ipView.setText(inetAddress.getHostAddress());
                       EditText et1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            et1.setText(inetAddress.getHostAddress());

                         }
                     }
                 }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("------------", e.toString());
            }
```

And the value will be set there.. :)

Comment: Thnx for your help, but i tried my method and that worked, actually i had set same id in both views,  creating a force close bug. It's solved now.

Comment: No prob.. m happy that you figured it out .. :)